# .apply on jquery deferred

Tags: jquery, promise

I have 2 deferreds. I need to pass the return values once one is rejected to the other one.

```
$d1.fail(function(){
    $d2.reject.apply($d2,arguments) ;
}) ;
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In general

Yes, but it's forward incompatible. jQuery are changing the deferred API in the next version to make their promises Promises/A+ compliant. Multiple values in deferred would no longer be supported.

So it is best to resolve your deferreds (or reject them) with a single argument for future compatibility.

#### That said, your code is suspicious

Usually when people have a deferred in a deferred it's because of [the deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Promises chain and it is generally preferable to create new promises using `.then` instead of creating a new deferred explicitly. This of course also takes of error handling for you.

Comment: Can you give an example of how will this be done using then. Is it $d1.then($d2.resolve, $d2.reject) ?

Comment: @Daniel sure thing.  Does the example on the linked question on the deferred anti pattern look like your code? If it doesn't can you create a gist or fiddle showing the relevant parts of your code where `$d1` and `$d2` interact?

Comment: @Daniel doing `$d1.then($d2.resolve, $d2.reject)` is actually another anti-pattern called the `then(success, fail)` antipattern https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern

Comment: Let me take some time to understand this anti patterns. Thanks.